# Does as.svrepdesign inherit the fpc from a svydesign object?

Tags: r, sampling, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I'm slightly confused by the `as.svrepdesign` function's use of the fpc from a design object.

The example from the documentation shows the following:

```
## one-stage cluster sample
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
## convert to bootstrap
bclus1<-as.svrepdesign(dclus1,type="bootstrap", replicates=100)
```

So that seems fine. My understanding is it will essentially use the bootstrap to compute statistics of interest over the survey design.

But is the FPC applied or not? The reason I suggest it is not is because if you choose "subbootstrap" the code runs fine. But it shouldn't. Subbootstrap is not available for finite population correction.

So I'm confused: Is the FPC applied or not when using `as.svrepdesign`? If it is not applied, I'm not entirely clear how to compute the vector required for `as.svrepdesign` for a one-cluster design.

**Update**

I'll add, I'm not the first to note the confusion around FPC and bootstrap resampling in the `survey` package. This is from [Mashreghi et al (2016)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistics-surveys/volume-10/issue-none/A-survey-of-bootstrap-methods-in-finite-population-sampling/10.1214/16-SS113.full):

> The user guide of version 3.30-3 of the package, dated February 20,
> 2015, presents the functions bootweights, subbootweights, and
> mrbweights. According to the documentation, “Bootstrap weights for
> infinite populations (’with replacement’ sampling) are created by
> sampling with replacement,” suggesting that the methods do not take
> into account that the population is finite. The function bootweights
> is deemed to implement the method of Canty and Davison (1999). But to
> simplify the discussion, that paper assumes that N/n is an integer and
> presents what seems like the algorithm of Gross (1980) and the case of
> a non-integer N/n is not discussed. Since the paper refers to Section
> 3.7 of Davison and Hinkley (1997), it suggests that bootweights implements the method of Booth et al. (1994). The function
> subbootweights seems to implement the Rao et al. (1992) method
> although the reference is incorrect and no finite population
> correction is included, i.e., it is as if f = 0 in the weights
> adjustment formula of Table 5 and so is not appropriate if the
> sampling fraction is large. On the other hand, it is clear that the
> function mrbweights is for the multistage method of Preston (2009).
> The documentation clearly mentions that “these bootstraps are strictly
> appropriate only when the first stage of sampling is a simple or
> stratified random sample of PSUs with or without replacement, and not
> (eg) for PPS sampling”. In fact, Preston’s method requires that simple
> random sampling be used at all stages, not only the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `fpc` is available for bootstrap and Preston's multi-scale bootstrap but not for Rao & Wu's n-1 bootstrap, it uses fpc for `bootstrap` and `mrb` but not for `subbootstrap` weights.